# valid data- variables for JavaScript Buttons

Tags: javascript, html, button

Is there a list of valid "data-??????" variables and their meanings?

e.g. data-amount = amount of transaction

Looking for table of variables used to make standard buttons with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

no limit: `data-*` ; * is anything (lowercase)

See the [documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes)